# Create community/portal for existing Account record

Tags: community, roles

Currently we are creating one community role for every new Account. Now we changed the setting and made it 2. FOr new Account it is creatin 2 Roles. how can I create 2 roles for existing portal account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create roles from Apex.

```
Id portalAcctId = '001xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
Integer roleCnt = [Select count() from UserRole where PortalAccountId = :portalAcctId];

//Execute the create logic if less than 3 roles exist as we can't add 4th role and system will throw an error
if(roleCnt < 3) {
 
    //Add one role, role will be added bottom up
    //If no roles exist, adds User
    //If 1 role (User) exists, adds Manager
    //If 2 roles (Manager, User) exist, adds Executive

    UserRole role = new UserRole();
    role.portalType = 'Partner'; // use 'CustomerPortal' for customer portal roles
    role.PortalAccountId = portalAcctId;
    role.CaseAccessForAccountOwner = 'Edit'; //Modify as needed
    role.OpportunityAccessForAccountOwner = 'Read'; //Modify as needed
    insert role;
}
```

[Create Portal roles programmatically using Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000329616&type=1)